# mongoDB (result= signal , code = killed , signal = ill

Tags: linux, mongodb, signals, kill, failed-to-connect

while i want to active mongo on linux i get this error and it and it wont work

---

$ sudo systemctl status mongod

● mongod.service - MongoDB Database Server
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
Active: failed (Result: signal) since Sun 2021-08-01 13:39:18 +03; 47s ago
Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
Process: 12854 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf (code=killed, signal=ILL)
Main PID: 12854 (code=killed, signal=ILL)
CPU: 19ms

Aug 01 13:39:18 jr systemd[1]: Started MongoDB Database Server.
Aug 01 13:39:18 jr systemd[1]: mongod.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=4/ILL
Aug 01 13:39:18 jr systemd[1]: mongod.service: Failed with result 'signal'.

---

and while i type mongod
it say

$ mongod
zsh: illegal hardware instruction  mongod

Answer (score 4):

i had the same problem with the same message. Seems to be a problem of processor compability.

Found this post https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/mongodb-5-0-cpu-intel-g4650-compatibility/116610

Check if your pocessor has the flags mentioned in the answer with the command:

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo
```

if not, you can try with an older version of mongo.
In my case my processor can't handle mongo4.4, but installed mongo4.2 and works fine, but depends of your processor and SO.

Comment: This answer was extremely useful! I wish I could give a bounty directly to the answer. (Don't want to start a bounty on the question that's already been answered.)

Answer (score 1):

Downgrade to 4.4

first, remove MongoDB

```
sudo apt-get purge mongodb-org*

sudo rm -r /var/log/mongodb

sudo rm -r /var/lib/mongodb

sudo rm -rf /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-5.0.list
```

install MongoDB 4.4

```
wget -qO - https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-4.4.asc | sudo apt- 
key add -
```

This worked for me seems to be a hardware problem, especially the CPU

Answer (score 0):

Also had the same problem and the above answer did help tremendously, but I found a couple stuff missing. My issue was also of the processor compatibility and required to uninstall the version I had installed and install a earlier version of MongoDB.

Here are the steps I followed, that did it for me

First, Uninstall the MongoDB version you had installed, requires removing the used repo from the `sources.list`, otherwise it will just keep installing that one (or latest version), even after uninstalling it. So to remove the repo from the `sources.list` follow these steps:

- List the contents of sources.list directory using

  ```
  ls -l /etc/apt/sources.list.d/
  ```
- Remove the repo(s) using the command

  ```
  sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/<repo_name>
  ```

Once the repo(s) are removed, uninstall MongoDB. Use these commands:

```
sudo apt purge mongodb-org*
sudo rm -r /var/log/mongodb
sudo rm -r /var/lib/mongodb
```

After uninstalling MongoDB, you might want to update the package list, so use

```
sudo apt update
```

From here onward, you can follow the steps for installing the lower version of MongoDB you want as [outlined in the manual](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/administration/install-on-linux/). Just make sure you select the version you want.

If it happens that the earlier version you get to also throws the same error, repeat the process, going to an earlier version still.

Answer (score 0):

same for me on a proxmox VM using mongodb-7.0
I just had to change my default CPU type
from x86-64-v2-AES to x86-64-v4

Comment: This is just a commet not an answer.