# Mongod does not start: mongod.service: Failed with result 'signal'

Tags: mongodb

I currently have MongoDB 4.4 installed, as my system does not support 5.0. I have previously had 4.4 installed on Arch Linux, however when I moved over to Ubuntu and tried to run mongod, I get this result from systemd:

```
● mongod.service - MongoDB Database Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: signal) since Fri 2021-12-10 15:57:00 CST; 2min 3s ago
       Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
    Process: 4369 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf (code=killed, signal=ILL)
   Main PID: 4369 (code=killed, signal=ILL)

Dec 10 15:57:00 system systemd[1]: Started MongoDB Database Server.
Dec 10 15:57:00 system systemd[1]: mongod.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=4/ILL
Dec 10 15:57:00 system systemd[1]: mongod.service: Failed with result 'signal'.
```

MongoDB fails before logs can be created.

Comment: it looks similar to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68609678/mongodb-result-signal-code-killed-signal-ill

Comment: Did you check the logfile?

Comment: it literally says at the bottom that mongodb fails before a log file can be created @WernfriedDomscheit

Comment: I mean the mongod log file, typically `/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log`. Location is defined in your `/etc/mongod.conf`

Comment: That log did not exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While this doesn't completely solve the issue, I'm fine with this resolution:
For whatever reason, 4.2 works fine, but 4.4 doesn't, even though I was completely fine running 4.4 on Arch.